# can not build qtermwidget from source

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-sip

I'm trying to build [qtermwidget](https://github.com/lxqt/qtermwidget) from source, but it gives me error.
I've successfully built [lxqt-build-tools](https://github.com/lxqt/lxqt-build-tools/) and then installed pyqt5 from both pip3 and apt:

```
sudo -H pip3 install -U pyqt5 pyqtwebengine
sudo apt install python3-sip-dev python3-pyqt5
```

and then I ran this:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/EAF && cd /tmp/EAF
git clone https://github.com/lxqt/qtermwidget  
cd qtermwidget  
mkdir build && cd build  
cmake .. -DQTERMWIDGET_BUILD_PYTHON_BINDING=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR=/usr
```

and it works fine. but when I run `make` command, it gives me this error:

```
[ 87%] Built target qtermwidget5
Byte-compiling /tmp/EAF/qtermwidget/build/pyqt//__init__.py to /tmp/EAF/qtermwidget/build/pyqt//__pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.pyc
[ 87%] Built target __tmp_EAF_qtermwidget_build_pyqt____pycache_____init__.cpython-36.pyc
[ 89%] Generating sip/sipQTermWidgetpart0.cpp, sip/sipQTermWidgetpart1.cpp, sip/sipQTermWidgetpart2.cpp, sip/sipQTermWidgetpart3.cpp, sip/sipQTermWidgetpart4.cpp, sip/sipQTermWidgetpart5.cpp, sip/sipQTermWidgetpart6.cpp, sip/sipQTermWidgetpart7.cpp

sip: Unable to find file "QtGui/QtGuimod.sip"
pyqt/CMakeFiles/python_module_QTermWidget.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'pyqt/sip/sipQTermWidgetpart0.cpp' failed
make[2]: *** [pyqt/sip/sipQTermWidgetpart0.cpp] Error 1
make[2]: *** Deleting file 'pyqt/sip/sipQTermWidgetpart0.cpp'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:179: recipe for target 'pyqt/CMakeFiles/python_module_QTermWidget.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [pyqt/CMakeFiles/python_module_QTermWidget.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I'm using `gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0` and `cmake version 3.16.0` and `GNU Make 4.1` in elementary OS 5.1 Hera. I once tried building `sip` and `pyqt5` from source, didn't change anything for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PyQt5 distributed by Ubuntu does not share the necessary .sip to compile QTermWidget so it is necessary to compile sip and pyqt5 manually. It seems you tried and it didn't work since it seems you used the wrong flags. Considering the above, I analyzed how sip, pyqt5 and qtermwidget are compiled in Arch Linux and managed to implement a [Dockerfile](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/59229716) that allowed me to compile QTermWidget.

So considering the above the procedure is:

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get install \
    -y --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential \
    git \
    ca-certificates \
    wget \
    cmake \
    pkg-config \
    python3-dev \
    libglib2.0-dev \
    qt5-default \
    qttools5-dev

mkdir -p /tmp/EAF

cd /tmp/EAF && \
    git clone https://github.com/lxqt/lxqt-build-tools.git \
    && cd lxqt-build-tools \
    && mkdir build && cd build \
    && cmake .. \
    && make && sudo make install

cd /tmp/EAF && \
    wget https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Downloads/sip/4.19.19/sip-4.19.19.tar.gz && \
    tar xvzf sip-4.19.19.tar.gz && \
    cd sip-4.19.19 && \
    python3 configure.py --sip-module PyQt5.sip && \
    make && \
    sudo make install

cd /tmp/EAF && \
    wget https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Downloads/PyQt5/5.13.2/PyQt5-5.13.2.tar.gz && \
    tar xvzf PyQt5-5.13.2.tar.gz && \
    cd PyQt5-5.13.2 && \
    python3 configure.py --confirm-license && \
    make && \
    sudo make install

cd /tmp/EAF && \
    git clone https://github.com/lxqt/qtermwidget \
    && cd qtermwidget \
    && mkdir build && cd build \
    && cmake .. -DQTERMWIDGET_BUILD_PYTHON_BINDING=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR=/lib \
    && make && sudo make install
```